# Splitting strings with discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

I want to create a bot that on command will output "(thing in command) was given".

For example: ?give food --> "food was given"

This is my feeble attempt at creating something like this (modified off of someone else's code) -it doesn't work:

```
@client.command()
async def give(message):
    str = message.content.split(" ")[0].replace("give", "")
    await message.channel.send("**(A) "+str+" was given**")
```

Comment: What is the question? or problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first argument to a command must always be a `Context` object, so we need a second argument to be the item that is given. Here I use a [keyword-only argument](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments) so that it allows spaces.

```
@client.command()
async def give(ctx, *, arg):
    await ctx.send(f"**(A) {arg} was given**")
```